# Qt Draw rectangle on Widget

Tags: c++, qt

I need to draw rectangle on a widget which is child item of mainWindow. But the below code not succeed on drawing the Widget, it's drawing on parent screen.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent (QPaintEvent *e)
{
 QPainter *painter = new QPainter (ui->widget);
 painter->begin (this);
 painter->drawRect(e->rect());
 painter->end ();
}

void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){

    update((QRect(LastPoint,event->pos())));
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        LastPoint = event->pos();
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**mainwindow.hpp**

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void paintEvent (QPaintEvent *e);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    QPoint LastPoint;

    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

I have attached the screenshot of the designer.

[image]

Comment: You need to override draw method of your widget, not of main window.

Comment: You're trying to draw on the `MainWindow`. Subclass `QWidget` and use the `paintEvent` there to paint your stuff. Then add this widget to your `QGroupBox`.

Comment: By the way, you have memory leak in `MainWindow::paintEvent`, `QPainter` not `QObject`, it is not freed by parent object.

Comment: @thuga Can you provide  any reference example?

Comment: You could check the [scribble example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html), if it's drawing you have problems with. In the example the `ScribbleArea` widget is set as the central widget. In your case you'd add it in your group box instead.

Comment: Actually I have seen that example, but I am conduced how can I add custom class to UI designer, and in that example it seems not using ui designer for creating the UI

Comment: Check [using custom widgets with qt designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Is it possible to add the UI element programmically as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824661/qt-gui-design-programmatically  in the case scribble example like you said above.

Comment: Yes. You just include the header of your class. Then somewhere in your mainwindow.cpp: `MyWidget *widget = new MyWidget;` `ui->groupBox->layout()->addWidget(widget);`. Make sure you set a layout to your groupbox first. Using the Qt Designer is completely optional. You can do everything programatically if you choose so.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply.

Comment: Also look at [QRubberBand](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrubberband.html)